# html <span> tags around tables, lists

Tags: css, tags, html

I am working on a project where I am sending html to a PDF creator, so I'm not too worried about proper html as long as it shows up correctly on the PDF.

I am currently working on a PDF where about half the page is in a different size font than the other.  I was hoping to accomplish this easily by putting  tags around the selection.  However, there are tables and lists which are not inheriting the css styles.

For example:

CSS:

```
.fs8
{
    font-size:8pt;
}
```

HTML:

```
...
<p>Size 10 text here...</p>

<span class='fs8'>

<p>This text is size 8</p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>This text is NOT size 8</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<p>Still size 8...</p>

<ul>
    <li>NOT size 8!
</ul>

</span>

<p>Size 10 again...</p>
```

Is there any good way to span across tables and lists, so I don't have to add class tags in hundreds of places?

Comment: You should make your html code as clean and as correct as possible. It will allow better understand issues with formatting.

Comment: I understand this, and I wouldn't be trying to do these cheesy shortcuts if I was making an actual webpage.  But I'm just looking for the easiest way to accomplish my goal (whether "correct" html or not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use a div instead of a span because span is by default an inline element, meaning it should not contain block level elements, such as table or ul. Now for the CSS.

```
.fs8 {
  font-size: 8px;
}
.fs8 table,
.fs8 ul {
  font-size: 10px; /* not 8px */
}
```

That should do the trick. You will not need to add classes to any items except the wrapping **div**, remember it cannot be a span, so replace it with a div for proper behavior.

Comment: This is actually very helpful, and a great solution, thanks!  However, I failed to mention that I have a different css property (which includes tables, lists) for the body of the html which overrides the div styles.

Comment: Well, its not very easy to solve the problem when there are undisclosed requirements, such as no divs. You could use any other block level element, such as blockquote, just not an inline level element such as span.

Comment: Sorry, I believe I accidentally was still using span when I tried your solution... Using a <div>, this ended up working perfectly: .fs8, .fs8 table, .fs8 tr, .fs8 td, .fs8 ul, .fs8 li { font-size:8pt !important; } Thanks!!

Comment: No problem. Thanks for selecting my answer as the solution :)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if i got what you meant but from what i understand you want to refine your selectors.

Try this:

```
.fs8 td,
.fs8 li
{
    font-size:9pt;
}
```

This would set font-size  to 9pt in any `td` or `li` tag inside an element with class `fs8`.

Comment: I understand that I can do this, but that means I have to go and add hundreds of class tags to each list item and table cell... I was hoping there was an easier way to accomplish this.

Comment: As in my original post: I'm trying to find the easiest way to make one half of my html page a different font size than the other half (where the page includes lots of tables and lists)

Comment: you would only need to add the .sf8 to the parent table and ul tags, not the td and li tags. How many tables and unordered lists do you have?

Comment: I apologize, I didn't look at the answer close enough... This works perfectly, but I needed to use a DIV: .fs8, .fs8 table, .fs8 tr, .fs8 td, .fs8 ul, .fs8 li { font-size:8pt !important; }

Answer (score 1):

Using `span` tags around `table` elements is simply invalid markup, so all bets are off. Consider using `div` instead or directly assigning the desired CSS properties to applicable elements.

Comment: I tried putting the selection inside a <div> as well, but it didn't appear to work any differently than the <span> tag

Comment: Then you are using Quirks Mode, or you have other CSS settings that override the settings you are trying to make. You are not giving enough information. What is certain is that `span` cannot validly contain `table`.

Comment: span elements are `display:inline` by default, putting block elements inside them is something I'd try to avoid.

Comment: It would be odd (though technically possible) for a user agent to have any default settings for `div` beyond `display: block`, so I’m pretty sure the reason is something completely different. Consider posting sufficient facts.

Comment: The user agent stylesheet was effecting the tables and lists, not the divs... found a solution, though... thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I know you don't want to do the class tags but you don't have to put it on all of them. you can just put a div around the entire thing, not a span tag those can be overridden by outer settings. I have had that issue before so do something like this:

```
    <div id="my_settings">

     <table>.....
     </table>

     <ul>....
     </ul>


     </div>
```

then in your css do this:

```
     #my_settings li, #my_settings li, #my_settings p{
         font-siz: ....;
     }
```

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you want but it might be easier than adding a class to all of them.

Comment: do you have a link for an example?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want a quick and possibly dirty solution, you could use the wildcard selector

```
.fs8, .fs8 *, .fs8 * *, .fs * * * { font-size:8pt; }
```

(you need all 3 for tables (span > table > tr > td)

Although, be warned that there might be undesirable side effects!

Also, you should be careful about the tool you use to generate PDF, some generate the file using an old browser rendering engine (hello ie6 rendering). In fact, it's probably why you are having issue, as [this example works perfectly](http://jsfiddle.net/QD9TM/) on ie8, but not in quirk modes..

Comment: It's ok, I would try to avoid this myself anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your question, but I will try to anwser:

```
p { font-size:10px; }
.fs8 p { font-size:8px; }
```

or

```
p, td, li { font-size: 10px; }
span.fs8 p { font-size:8px; }
```